# Is there a way to get rid of union all and combine several blocks into one? (Hive SQL)

Tags: sql, hive, union-all

I have a table with the following fields: `start_date`, `end_date` and `traffic`. I need to group data by every year and month from `2020-01-01` and sum `traffic` field. The tricky moment is that the year and month are not tied to the `start_date` and `end_date`. For example, in the resulting table for the year=2023 and month=2, the traffic sum calculated like this:

```
select
   2023 as year,
   2 as month,
   sum(traffic) as traffic
from table
where start_date <= '2023-02-01' and end_date >= '2023-02-01'
```

`start_date` and `end_date` values are between '1998-01-01' and now

With `union all` the required script looks like this:

```
select
   2020 as year,
   1 as month,
   sum(traffic) as traffic
from table
where start_date <= '2020-01-01' and end_date >= '2020-01-01'

union all

select
   2020 as year,
   2 as month,
   sum(traffic) as traffic
from table
where start_date <= '2020-02-01' and end_date >= '2020-02-01'

union all

select
   2020 as year,
   3 as month,
   sum(traffic) as traffic
from table
where start_date <= '2020-03-01' and end_date >= '2020-03-01'

union all

...
...
...

select
   2024 as year,
   3 as month,
   sum(traffic) as traffic
from table
where start_date <= '2024-03-01' and end_date >= '2024-03-01'
```

How to get rid of `union all` and make the script more compact? I tried to create a separate table selecting all dates from 1998, then calculating year, month, and first date of the month for every date. Example:

| date | month | year | first_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1998-01-01 | 1 | 1998 | 1998-01-01 |
| 1998-01-02 | 1 | 1998 | 1998-01-01 |
| 1998-01-03 | 1 | 1998 | 1998-01-01 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Then I joined this table with the source table and got this script:

```
select
   d.year,
   d.month,
   sum(traffic) as traffic
from table as t
join generated_dated as d on d.date = t.start_date
where start_date <= d.first_date and end_date >= d.first_date
group by
   d.year,
   d.month
```

But the results were wrong.

Data sample:

| row | start_date | end_date | traffic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-09-15 | 2019-02-13 | 11 |
| 2 | 2019-02-03 | 2021-03-05 | 12 |
| 3 | 2019-09-03 | 2022-03-05 | 2 |
| 4 | 2020-01-15 | 2023-04-02 | 4 |
| 5 | 2020-01-30 | 2022-10-19 | 4 |
| 6 | 2020-02-01 | 2020-02-02 | 7 |
| 7 | 2020-02-13 | 2020-02-19 | 9 |
| 8 | 2020-02-14 | 2020-07-05 | 15 |
| 9 | 2020-03-09 | 2022-08-08 | 24 |
| 10 | 2020-05-12 | 2022-09-01 | 24 |
| 11 | 2020-06-19 | 2024-02-05 | 11 |

For this data sample results should be:

| year | month | traffic sum | *condition | *calculation for traffic sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1 | 14 | "start_date <= '2020-01-01' and end_date >= '2020-01-01'" | 'row2+row3' |
| 2020 | 2 | 29 | "start_date <= '2020-02-01' and end_date >= '2020-02-01'" | 'row2+row3+row4+row5+row6' |
| 2020 | 3 | 37 | "start_date <= '2020-03-01' and end_date >= '2020-03-01'" | 'row2+row3+row4+row5+row8' |
| 2020 | 4 | 61 | "start_date <= '2020-04-01' and end_date >= '2020-04-01'" | 'row2+row3+row4+row5+row8+row9' |
| 2020 | 5 | 61 | "start_date <= '2020-05-01' and end_date >= '2020-05-01'" | 'row2+row3+row4+row5+row8+row9' |
| 2020 | 6 | 85 | "start_date <= '2020-06-01' and end_date >= '2020-06-01'" | 'row2+row3+row4+row5+row8+row9+row10' |
| 2020 | 7 | 96 | "start_date <= '2020-07-01' and end_date >= '2020-07-01'" | 'row2+row3+row4+row5+row8+row9+row10+row11' |
| 2020 | 8 | 81 | "start_date <= '2020-08-01' and end_date >= '2020-08-01'" | 'row2+row3+row4+row5+row9+row10+row11' |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2024 | 1 | 11 | "start_date <= '2024-01-01' and end_date >= '2024-01-01'" | 'row11' |
| 2024 | 2 | 11 | "start_date <= '2024-02-01' and end_date >= '2024-02-01'" | 'row11' |
| 2024 | 3 | 0 | "start_date <= '2024-03-01' and end_date >= '2024-03-01'" | 'no rows' |

I am using `Hive SQL`.

Comment: On your final query you are missing a `GROUP BY d.year, d.month`

Comment: @Charlieface misprint, tnx

Comment: @jarlh nope, group by is only needed for the last query

Comment: @MagomedKhashiev, yes, correct!

Comment: To answer your question fully please provide some sample data. The sample should be representative of actual data but we don't need a huge amount of it. Please provide DDL and DML if possible or at least in text tables so we can create and insert into the 2 tables involved. Or create a https://dbfiddle.uk and supply the url to that.

Comment: nb: I believe only sample data will help explain this: *"The tricky moment is that the year and month are not tied to the start_date and end_date"* at the moment only you can see the data, but we need to see some too

Comment: @AdrianMaxwell added examples with calculations

Comment: This is how I would approach your problem: https://dbfiddle.uk/0LdLUOaz I want a series of dates then left join that to the data and aggregate, this way I get all the dates I want (even if there is no matching traffic data). Note I used Postgres in my example, you will need to modify to suit the dbms you actually use.

Comment: @MagomedKhashiev has this issue been solved now? Do you require more?

Comment: @AdrianMaxwell solved, thx, i used your example

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what you need, first of all, it should be done cross join to find relation between start and end date between necessary table and after that filtering fulfilled conditions

```
select 
example_date,
sum(traffic)

from sample_table 
full join dates
on 1=1
where example_date >= start_date and example_date <= end_date
group by example_date
ORDER by example_date
```